# Exception thrown: read access violation. **_Right_data** was 0x8. occurred

Tags: c++

If condition in the addToHashTable() function throws exception: Exception thrown: read access violation. **_Right_data** was 0x8. occurred.
hashTable is pointer type getNode() returns string. so when i call getNode it returns the word present in it . then i want to compare this word with empty string to check if the Node is empty or not but at this line exception is thrown.Anyone please help me how i get over with this exception

```
static int const hashTableSize = 15;
Node *hashTable[hashTableSize];
.........................................................
void HashTable::addToHashTable(int hashIndex, string word)
{
    Node *node = new Node(word);
    if (hashTable[hashIndex]->getNode() == "")//exception throws at this 
    {``
        hashTable[hashIndex] = node;
    }
    else
    {
        if (hashTable[hashIndex]->getNode() != word)
        {
            node->link = hashTable[hashIndex];
            hashTable[hashIndex] = node;
        }
    }
    return;
}
.............................................
string Node::getNode()
{
    return this->word;
}
..........................................
class Node
{
public:
    Node *link;
    Node *pointNextWrongWord;
    Node();
    Node(string word);
    string getNode();
    ~Node();

private:
    string word;
    int priority;
};
................................
Main:
cout << "Type the word you want to add in Dictionary : ";
cin >> word;
hashIndex = hashTable.hashFunction(word);
hashTable.addToHashTable(hashIndex, word);

i expect this if condition compare the string returned by getNode() 
function with "" (empty string) rather than throwing exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code , I had the impression that no memory is allocated foth the hashTable.

This piece of code is not correct

```
if (hashTable[hashIndex]->getNode() == "")//exception throws at this 
{
    hashTable[hashIndex] = node;
}
```

Probably you need an initialization routing that set string word to " "

```
init()
   { 
      for (int i =0 ; i < sizeof(hashTable)/sizeof(hasTable[0]); ++i)
      {
          hashTable[hashIndex] = new Node("");

      }
   }
```

Comment: i dont understand if this initialization is to done in constructor or what?

Comment: You have an unitialized  array of pointes of the type Node (*hashTable[hashTableSize]) .. Before access any element of this aray you shoukd initiliaze this . In main before start read the words from console you should call the init function